# Can I access constants defined in constant.php file in codeigniter from non-controller php file which is background script file?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web

I am beginner for php and codeigniter.

I have a controller and other background php script file. From controller, i wish to set constants for username and password after user logged in. These will be stored in constant.php file. Now, as i said, i wish access these constants from background php script. This php script file is non-controller file which is stored in same directory in which controller is stored.

Or is there any way to store these username ans password somewhere and i can acess those from non-controller php files. This file contains the function definitions which i called them from controllers.

Comment: You can make constant.php a model, then in whatever controller, load the model and pass data to view.  Or you can make the constants values as session values. Third choice --- Storing the data in database is the most secure choice.

Comment: Can multiple users be logged in at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Store them in config/config.php e.g. `$config['currency_symbol'] = "$";` then you can use in your application with `$this->config->item('currency_symbol')`

Comment: There should be better places to store constans than config file

Comment: can i access them from background script file which is non-controller file(its not a controller,model or view but a simple file which contains the all function definitions and these are called from controller file. )

Comment: yes, this can be done with the help of CodeIgniter libraries, to know how to use them check [Creating Libraries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: you can convert your file (contain all the methods) into class, put that file under application/libraries, constant can be use in that file and method defined in the file can be used anywhere in your application by creating an object of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Nav Jav is the recommended way when you create global constants and functions. It is what MVC means.

Anyway, you can put your constant.php in your "application" folder. For example your constant.php is something like:

```
//File name constant.php, path is application\myfolder\constant.php
<?php
    $test = 1;
    function test($string){
        return $string.' got';
    }
?>
```

In the views or controllers or models where you want to use the constants and the functions, you can do:

```
<?php
    require_once(APPPATH.'myfolder/constant.php');
    echo test('string1'); //which will give you 'strint1 got'
    echo $test; //which will give you 1
?>
```

Again, this is not recommended, you should follow Nav Jav's way.